# Linking Freetype library to Xcode project

Tags: xcode, freetype

I'm having trouble using the Freetype library in my Xcode project and have the include at the top of my code `#include <ft2build.h>`
; however when I build the code, I get the error 'Ft2build.h' No Such file or directory. I had linked the library 'libfreetype.dylib' and included the following in 'Other Link Flags' in the Build tab: '-l/usr/local/include/freetype2/'.

I'm quite new to Xcode, and would appreciate any help here from someone that could highlight what I've missed.

Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: That's a compiler error, not a linker error.

Comment: @trojanfoe Hi thanks for the clarification of the nature of the error; would you know why I'm getting the compile error?

Comment: Does `ft2build.h` exist in `/usr/include` (or some other include directory)?

Comment: @trojanfoe Hi that exists in: `/usr/local/include/freetype2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are putting (the necessary) `-I/usr/local/include/freetype2` flags in *Other Linker Flags* and the linker doesn't care about include files.

Instead modify the *Header Search Path* in the *Build Settings*.

You will probably also need to modify the *Library Search Path* as well, in order to pickup the library.

Avoid using *Other Linker Flags* if you can help it.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, that's fixed the issue; learning a bit more each time I use Xcode. Best regards, Alex

Answer (score 3):

To link with freetype2 on macOS in XCode, determine the header/lib paths by running the following two commands in the terminal:

```
freetype-config --cflags    // example output: -I/opt/X11/include/freetype2
freetype-config --libs      // example output: -L/opt/X11/lib -lfreetype
```

... and change the Xcode project-setting accordingly:

```
"Header Search Paths"   => /opt/X11/include/freetype2
"Library Search Paths"  => /opt/X11/lib
"Other Linker Flags"    => -lfreetype
```